# How to find and label dominant peaks in a plot

Tags: plotting, labeling

I've created a dynamic plot for different musical instruments using the following code:

```
Manipulate[
fs = 44100;
data = AudioData[
Audio[Sound[SoundNote[pitch, {0, 2}, instrument]], 
 SampleRate -> fs]][[1, All]];
ft = Fourier[data, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}];
nl = Dimensions[ft][[1]]/2;
temp = Drop[Drop[Chop[ft], -nl], 1];
freq = Flatten[SparseArray[Abs[temp]]["NonzeroPositions"]];
amp = SparseArray[Abs[temp]]["NonzeroValues"]*2;
pha = SparseArray[Arg[temp]]["NonzeroValues"];
ListLinePlot[amp, PlotRange -> {{1, 15000}, All}],
{{pitch, "A"}, {"A" -> "A", "B" -> "B", "C" -> "C", "D" -> "D"}},
{{instrument, "Flute" -> "Flute"}, {"Flute" -> "Flute", 
"Violin" -> "Violin", "Bass" -> "Bass", "Clarinet" -> "Clarinet"}}]
```

and I get a sample plot as given below:

[image]

Now I wish to find the dominant peaks and display the coordinates at the top of the peaks.

I tried with FindPeaks but didn't get the desired result.

Is there any smart way to do this?

Edit 1: For musical instruments, the desired peaks should at an exactly same interval as shown in the plot clearly. Estimating the threshold is a good choice where the peaks values stand out significantly against the noise. However, when it becomes comparable (for example signals around 7000 and 9000), simple thresholding does not provide the desired result. Is it possible to find the peaks based on a priori knowledge that the peaks should occur at an approximately same interval?

Comment: First thought is to use a value criterium for the peaks, allowing to isolate portions of the list containing the peaks. There you can find value and position of the max.

Comment: What *exactly* was wrong with the `FindPeaks` result, so we can perhaps better understand what the problem is?

Comment: @MacroB : FindPeaks gives all the peaks while I'm interested only on the major peaks.

Comment: I've edited the image to indicate which peaks I want.

Comment: From the documentation: `FindPeaks[data,\[Sigma],s,t], finds only peaks with values greater than t`

Comment: To expand on @Feyre 's comment, use `FindPeaks[amp, 0, 0, yourThresholdValue]` to have the function return peaks higher than the set threshold.

Comment: To be quite fair and blunt, before your comment above or the edit, you neglected to give a definite criterion on what a "major peak" ought to be.

Comment: @J.M. : The major peaks in the spectrum of a musical instrument note is very clearly defined in the literature. There exists one fundamental frequency and the other dominant frequencies are multiples of the fundamental. Look at the audio spectrum of a flute (http://physics.info/music/)

Answer (score 5):

Take a snapshot of your `Manipulate` as an example:

```
{instrument = "Flute" -> "Flute", pitch = "A", fs = 44100};
data = AudioData[Audio[Sound[SoundNote[pitch, {0, 2}, instrument]], 
    SampleRate -> fs]][[1, All]]; 
ft = Fourier[data, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}]; 
nl = 1/2 Dimensions[ft][[1]]; 
temp = Drop[Drop[Chop[ft], -nl], 1];  
amp = SparseArray[Abs[temp]]["NonzeroValues"] 2;
```

Use `FindPeaks` to find all the values greater than `0.0005` with a blurring scale `100`. Ideally, you would want to write a function to detect these parameters depending on the data.

```
In[77]:= p = FindPeaks[amp, 100, 0, 0.0005];

In[78]:= Length[p]

Out[78]= 18
```

For efficiency, plot the amp and labels in different plots in log scale. Here I use the new `Callout` with some options.

```
l = ListLogPlot[p, LabelingFunction -> (Callout[#1, Above, 
   LeaderSize -> {{10, 90 Degree, Automatic}, {10, 90 Degree}}] &),
   PlotStyle -> Red];

m = ListLogPlot[amp, PlotRange -> {{1, 15000}, All},    
   PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, {Automatic, Scaled[0.2]}}, 
   Joined -> True];
```

Combine them:

```
Show[m, l, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was exactly looking for. However, using the same threshold for peaks, I am getting a different set of values - {{1, 0.000511076}, {889, 0.110259}, {1784, 0.143907}, {2703, 
  0.0776711}, {3569, 0.0337469}, {3576, 0.0565324}, {4464, 
  0.0275612}, {5353, 0.00665298}, {6295, 0.00437954}, {7198, 
  0.00209214}, {8040, 0.00098213}, {9006, 0.00144679}, {9817, 
  0.0008523}} for Flute ->A. Can you please check it once more? Secondly, instead of using ListLogPlot, can it be displayed using LIstLinePlot?

Comment: Just switch the two ListLogPlot to ListPlot or ListLinePlot.
I am not sure why you get the different results, though. However, you can change those parameters to see if it gives you better results.